# Is it possible to modify this function in my database?

Tags: sql, mysql

I would like to modify a function in my schema. When it calculates the other_leave_count_per_staff, it's getting the data from leave_type_table. In the table, i have a column calculate_efte, true or false (1 and 0). But in my function, i would like to add another calculation for operation, but when i change 0 to 1 in leave_type, it's also calculating it for administration.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `generate_efte_date_type_table`(par_date_range_type VARCHAR(45), par_property_record_key TEXT, par_date_year YEAR) RETURNS text CHARSET utf8mb4
    NO SQL
BEGIN
    DECLARE temp_date_type_factor INT DEFAULT 1; 
    DECLARE temp_number_days INT;
    DECLARE temp_number_weeks DECIMAL(10,2);
     
    SELECT DAYOFYEAR(CONCAT(par_date_year, '-12-31')) INTO temp_number_days;
    SET temp_number_weeks = temp_number_days / 7;
    IF par_date_range_type = 'daily' THEN
        SET temp_date_type_factor = temp_number_days;
    ELSEIF par_date_range_type = 'weekly' THEN
        SET temp_date_type_factor = temp_number_weeks; 
    ELSEIF par_date_range_type = 'monthly' THEN
        SET temp_date_type_factor = 12;
    ELSEIF par_date_range_type = 'quarterly' THEN
        SET temp_date_type_factor = 4;
    ELSEIF par_date_range_type = 'semi_yearly' THEN
        SET temp_date_type_factor = 2;
    END IF;

    SET @administration_other_leave_count_calculation = "`efte`.`administration_staff_count` * `efte`.`other_leave_count_per_staff`";
    SET @operation_other_leave_count_calculation = "`efte`.`operation_staff_count` * `efte`.`other_leave_count_per_staff`";

    RETURN CONCAT("(
        SELECT 
            `efte`.`property_record_key` AS `property_record_key`,
            `efte`.`property_display_name_short_code` AS `property_display_name_short_code`,
            `efte`.`property_hex_color_code` AS `property_hex_color_code`,
            IFNULL((((`efte`.`weekly_working_hour_administration` * ", temp_number_weeks, " * `efte`.`administration_staff_count`)
                - (`efte`.`daily_working_hour_administration` * (`efte`.`administration_annual_leave_count` + `efte`.`administration_ph_count` * `efte`.`ph_count` + `efte`.`administration_sh_count` * `efte`.`sh_count` + ", @administration_other_leave_count_calculation, "))) / `efte`.`administration_staff_count` / ", temp_date_type_factor, "), 0) AS `administration_working_hour`,
            IFNULL((((`efte`.`weekly_working_hour_operation` * ", temp_number_weeks, " * `efte`.`operation_staff_count`)
                - (`efte`.`daily_working_hour_operation` * (`efte`.`operation_annual_leave_count` + `efte`.`operation_ph_count` * `efte`.`ph_count` + `efte`.`operation_sh_count` * `efte`.`sh_count` + ", @operation_other_leave_count_calculation,"))) / `efte`.`operation_staff_count` / ", temp_date_type_factor, "), 0) AS `operation_working_hour`,
            (IFNULL((((`efte`.`weekly_working_hour_operation` * ", temp_number_weeks, " * `efte`.`operation_staff_count`)
                - (`efte`.`daily_working_hour_operation` * (`efte`.`operation_annual_leave_count` + `efte`.`operation_ph_count` * `efte`.`ph_count` + `efte`.`operation_sh_count` * `efte`.`sh_count` + ", @operation_other_leave_count_calculation,"))) / `efte`.`operation_staff_count` / ", temp_date_type_factor, "), 0)
            +
            IFNULL((((`efte`.`weekly_working_hour_administration` * ", temp_number_weeks, " * `efte`.`administration_staff_count`)
                - (`efte`.`daily_working_hour_administration` * (`efte`.`administration_annual_leave_count` + `efte`.`administration_ph_count` * `efte`.`ph_count` + `efte`.`administration_sh_count` * `efte`.`sh_count` + ", @administration_other_leave_count_calculation, "))) / `efte`.`administration_staff_count` / ", temp_date_type_factor, "), 0)) AS `all_working_hour`,
            IFNULL((`efte`.`weekly_working_hour_administration` * ", temp_number_weeks, "/ ", temp_date_type_factor, "),0) AS `administration_casual_working_hour`, 
            IFNULL((`efte`.`weekly_working_hour_operation` * ", temp_number_weeks, "/ ", temp_date_type_factor, "),0) AS `operation_casual_working_hour`,
            (IFNULL((`efte`.`weekly_working_hour_administration` * ", temp_number_weeks, "/ ", temp_date_type_factor, "),0)
            +
            IFNULL((`efte`.`weekly_working_hour_operation` * ", temp_number_weeks, "/ ", temp_date_type_factor, "),0)) AS `all_casual_working_hour`
        FROM 
            (SELECT 
                `p`.`record_key` AS `property_record_key`, 
                `p`.`display_name_short_code` AS `property_display_name_short_code`, 
                `p`.`hex_color_code` AS `property_hex_color_code`,
                IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN `s`.`staff_type` = 'Administration' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS `administration_staff_count`, 
                `ewh`.`daily_working_hour_administration` AS `daily_working_hour_administration`,
                `ewh`.`weekly_working_hour_administration` AS `weekly_working_hour_administration`,
                IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN `s`.`staff_type` = 'Administration' THEN `s`.`annual_leave` ELSE 0 END), 0) AS `administration_annual_leave_count`,
                IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN `s`.`staff_type` = 'Administration' AND `s`.`type_of_holiday` = 'PH' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS `administration_ph_count`,
                IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN `s`.`staff_type` = 'Administration' AND `s`.`type_of_holiday` = 'SH' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS `administration_sh_count`,
                IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN `s`.`staff_type` = 'Operation' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS `operation_staff_count`,
                `ewh`.`daily_working_hour_operation` AS `daily_working_hour_operation`,
                `ewh`.`weekly_working_hour_operation` AS `weekly_working_hour_operation`,
                IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN `s`.`staff_type` = 'Operation' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS `operation_annual_leave_count`,
                IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN `s`.`staff_type` = 'Operation' AND `s`.`type_of_holiday` = 'PH' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS `operation_ph_count`,
                IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN `s`.`staff_type` = 'Operation' AND `s`.`type_of_holiday` = 'SH' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS `operation_sh_count`,
                IFNULL(`hc`.`ph_count`, 0) AS `ph_count`,
                IFNULL(`hc`.`sh_count`, 0) AS `sh_count`,
                IFNULL(`lc`.`other_leave_count_per_staff`, 0) AS `other_leave_count_per_staff`
            FROM `staff` `s`
            JOIN `property` `p` ON `s`.`property_record_key` = `p`.`record_key` AND INSTR('", par_property_record_key, "', `p`.`record_key`)
            JOIN `employment_status` `es` ON `s`.`employment_status_record_key` = `es`.`record_key`
            JOIN `efte_working_hour` `ewh` ON `s`.`property_record_key` = `ewh`.`property_record_key`
            LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT
                    `h`.`property_record_key` AS `property_record_key`,
                    IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN `h`.`type_of_holiday` = 'PH' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS `ph_count`,
                    IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN `h`.`type_of_holiday` = 'SH' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS `sh_count`
                FROM
                    `holiday` `h` 
                WHERE `h`.`year_of_holiday` = '", par_date_year, "'
                GROUP BY `h`.`property_record_key`
            ) `hc` ON `s`.`property_record_key` = `hc`.`property_record_key`
            LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT `property_record_key`, SUM(`lt`.`default_days`) AS `other_leave_count_per_staff`
                FROM `leave_type` `lt`
                WHERE `calculate_efte` IS TRUE
                GROUP BY `lt`.`property_record_key`
            ) `lc` ON `s`.`property_record_key` = `lc`.`property_record_key`
            WHERE `s`.`record_status` = 'Active' AND LOWER(`es`.`permanent`) = 'yes'
            GROUP BY `s`.`property_record_key`
            ) `efte`) `efte_date_type`");
END
```

I tried creating a new table and creating the columns only for those shifts that i need, but when i join the tables together i get errors.

Comment: Can you share the error?

Comment: In leave_type table it is calculating only for example annual leave and sick leave. I have other rows, for example no paid leave etc. if i change the value of the column default_days and calculate_efte to 1, it is goint to make the calculation for administration as well based on the last join.

Comment: @HeinzSiahaan i'm trying to avoid creating a new table, because then I would have to modify all of my stored procedures and functions, basically all my schema . If there is a way i can modifiy this function it would be the best case.

Comment: copy the select add some value for your variables and run the code, then try to change it till it runs, with out any data or tables the query is too compex

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

please try following changes on new code:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `generate_efte_date_type_table`(par_date_range_type VARCHAR(45), par_property_record_key TEXT, par_date_year YEAR) RETURNS text CHARSET utf8mb4
    NO SQL
BEGIN
    DECLARE temp_date_type_factor INT DEFAULT 1; 
    DECLARE temp_number_days INT;
    DECLARE temp_number_weeks DECIMAL(10,2);
     
    SELECT DAYOFYEAR(CONCAT(par_date_year, '-12-31')) INTO temp_number_days;
    SET temp_number_weeks = temp_number_days / 7;
    IF par_date_range_type = 'daily' THEN
        SET temp_date_type_factor = temp_number_days;
    ELSEIF par_date_range_type = 'weekly' THEN
        SET temp_date_type_factor = temp_number_weeks; 
    ELSEIF par_date_range_type = 'monthly' THEN
        SET temp_date_type_factor = 12;
    ELSEIF par_date_range_type = 'quarterly' THEN
        SET temp_date_type_factor = 4;
    ELSEIF par_date_range_type = 'semi_yearly' THEN
        SET temp_date_type_factor = 2;
    END IF;

    -- Adjust calculations based on the value of calculate_efte
    SET @administration_other_leave_count_calculation = 
        CASE WHEN (SELECT calculate_efte FROM leave_type WHERE property_record_key = par_property_record_key) = 1 THEN
            "`efte`.`administration_staff_count` * `efte`.`other_leave_count_per_staff_modified`"
        ELSE
            "`efte`.`administration_staff_count` * `efte`.`other_leave_count_per_staff`"
        END;
        
    SET @operation_other_leave_count_calculation = 
        CASE WHEN (SELECT calculate_efte FROM leave_type WHERE property_record_key = par_property_record_key) = 1 THEN
            "`efte`.`operation_staff_count` * `efte`.`other_leave_count_per_staff_modified`"
        ELSE
            "`efte`.`operation_staff_count` * `efte`.`other_leave_count_per_staff`"
        END;

    -- Rest of your function code
    -- ...

END
```

this approach allows you to adgust the calculrtions within the function based on the condition you specified involving the calculate_efte column. Make sure to replace "other_leave_count_per_staff_modified" with the actual modified calculation you intend to use when calculate_efte is 1.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the variables you have defined for the two cases:

```
    SET @administration_other_leave_count_calculation = "`efte`.`administration_staff_count` * `efte`.`other_leave_count_per_staff`";
    SET @operation_other_leave_count_calculation = "`efte`.`operation_staff_count` * `efte`.`other_leave_count_per_staff`";
```

They multiply some scalar value (which may be `administration_staff_count` or `operation_staff_count`, respectively) with `other_leave_count_per_staff`, which is computed as

```
IFNULL(`lc`.`other_leave_count_per_staff`, 0) AS `other_leave_count_per_staff`
```

based on

```
            LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT `property_record_key`, SUM(`lt`.`default_days`) AS `other_leave_count_per_staff`
                FROM `leave_type` `lt`
                WHERE `calculate_efte` IS TRUE
                GROUP BY `lt`.`property_record_key`
            ) `lc` ON `s`.`property_record_key` = `lc`.`property_record_key`
```

Your problem-statement was that if you update `leave_type` and set `calculate_efte` to true, then it modifies the administration calculation as well, which implies that some `leave_type` records represent operation, others represent administration. And the solution for your case is to make a differentiation between the two, like:

```
            LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT `property_record_key`, SUM(`ld`.`IsAdmin` * `lt`.`default_days`) AS `other_leave_count_per_staff_admin`,
                SUM((1 - `ld`.`IsAdmin`) * `lt`.`default_days`) AS `other_leave_count_per_staff_operation`,
                FROM `leave_type` `lt`
                WHERE `calculate_efte` IS TRUE
                GROUP BY `lt`.`property_record_key`
            ) `lc` ON `s`.`property_record_key` = `lc`.`property_record_key`
```

and adjust your variables as

```
    SET @administration_other_leave_count_calculation = "`efte`.`administration_staff_count` * `efte`.`other_leave_count_per_staff_admin`";
    SET @operation_other_leave_count_calculation = "`efte`.`operation_staff_count` * `efte`.`other_leave_count_per_staff_operation`";
```

The problem is that you might lack an `IsAdmin` field. But, provided that you have an expression that evaluates to 0 if it's not an admin and 1 if it's an admin, you could replace `IsAdmin` with that expression. If the given expression gets superfluous, then you could implement a stored function to compute `IsAdmin`. Nevertheless, the need to cover here is the differentiation between admin and operational.

EDIT

You could join `leave_type` with `staff` to find out whether it's an admin or not, like:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `generate_efte_date_type_table`(par_date_range_type VARCHAR(45), par_property_record_key TEXT, par_date_year YEAR) RETURNS text CHARSET utf8mb4
    NO SQL
BEGIN
    DECLARE temp_date_type_factor INT DEFAULT 1; 
    DECLARE temp_number_days INT;
    DECLARE temp_number_weeks DECIMAL(10,2);
     
    SELECT DAYOFYEAR(CONCAT(par_date_year, '-12-31')) INTO temp_number_days;
    SET temp_number_weeks = temp_number_days / 7;
    IF par_date_range_type = 'daily' THEN
        SET temp_date_type_factor = temp_number_days;
    ELSEIF par_date_range_type = 'weekly' THEN
        SET temp_date_type_factor = temp_number_weeks; 
    ELSEIF par_date_range_type = 'monthly' THEN
        SET temp_date_type_factor = 12;
    ELSEIF par_date_range_type = 'quarterly' THEN
        SET temp_date_type_factor = 4;
    ELSEIF par_date_range_type = 'semi_yearly' THEN
        SET temp_date_type_factor = 2;
    END IF;

    SET @administration_other_leave_count_calculation = "`efte`.`administration_staff_count` * `efte`.`other_leave_count_per_staff_operation`";
    SET @operation_other_leave_count_calculation = "`efte`.`operation_staff_count` * `efte`.`other_leave_count_per_staff_administration`";

    RETURN CONCAT("(
        SELECT 
            `efte`.`property_record_key` AS `property_record_key`,
            `efte`.`property_display_name_short_code` AS `property_display_name_short_code`,
            `efte`.`property_hex_color_code` AS `property_hex_color_code`,
            IFNULL((((`efte`.`weekly_working_hour_administration` * ", temp_number_weeks, " * `efte`.`administration_staff_count`)
                - (`efte`.`daily_working_hour_administration` * (`efte`.`administration_annual_leave_count` + `efte`.`administration_ph_count` * `efte`.`ph_count` + `efte`.`administration_sh_count` * `efte`.`sh_count` + ", @administration_other_leave_count_calculation, "))) / `efte`.`administration_staff_count` / ", temp_date_type_factor, "), 0) AS `administration_working_hour`,
            IFNULL((((`efte`.`weekly_working_hour_operation` * ", temp_number_weeks, " * `efte`.`operation_staff_count`)
                - (`efte`.`daily_working_hour_operation` * (`efte`.`operation_annual_leave_count` + `efte`.`operation_ph_count` * `efte`.`ph_count` + `efte`.`operation_sh_count` * `efte`.`sh_count` + ", @operation_other_leave_count_calculation,"))) / `efte`.`operation_staff_count` / ", temp_date_type_factor, "), 0) AS `operation_working_hour`,
            (IFNULL((((`efte`.`weekly_working_hour_operation` * ", temp_number_weeks, " * `efte`.`operation_staff_count`)
                - (`efte`.`daily_working_hour_operation` * (`efte`.`operation_annual_leave_count` + `efte`.`operation_ph_count` * `efte`.`ph_count` + `efte`.`operation_sh_count` * `efte`.`sh_count` + ", @operation_other_leave_count_calculation,"))) / `efte`.`operation_staff_count` / ", temp_date_type_factor, "), 0)
            +
            IFNULL((((`efte`.`weekly_working_hour_administration` * ", temp_number_weeks, " * `efte`.`administration_staff_count`)
                - (`efte`.`daily_working_hour_administration` * (`efte`.`administration_annual_leave_count` + `efte`.`administration_ph_count` * `efte`.`ph_count` + `efte`.`administration_sh_count` * `efte`.`sh_count` + ", @administration_other_leave_count_calculation, "))) / `efte`.`administration_staff_count` / ", temp_date_type_factor, "), 0)) AS `all_working_hour`,
            IFNULL((`efte`.`weekly_working_hour_administration` * ", temp_number_weeks, "/ ", temp_date_type_factor, "),0) AS `administration_casual_working_hour`, 
            IFNULL((`efte`.`weekly_working_hour_operation` * ", temp_number_weeks, "/ ", temp_date_type_factor, "),0) AS `operation_casual_working_hour`,
            (IFNULL((`efte`.`weekly_working_hour_administration` * ", temp_number_weeks, "/ ", temp_date_type_factor, "),0)
            +
            IFNULL((`efte`.`weekly_working_hour_operation` * ", temp_number_weeks, "/ ", temp_date_type_factor, "),0)) AS `all_casual_working_hour`
        FROM 
            (SELECT 
                `p`.`record_key` AS `property_record_key`, 
                `p`.`display_name_short_code` AS `property_display_name_short_code`, 
                `p`.`hex_color_code` AS `property_hex_color_code`,
                IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN `s`.`staff_type` = 'Administration' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS `administration_staff_count`, 
                `ewh`.`daily_working_hour_administration` AS `daily_working_hour_administration`,
                `ewh`.`weekly_working_hour_administration` AS `weekly_working_hour_administration`,
                IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN `s`.`staff_type` = 'Administration' THEN `s`.`annual_leave` ELSE 0 END), 0) AS `administration_annual_leave_count`,
                IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN `s`.`staff_type` = 'Administration' AND `s`.`type_of_holiday` = 'PH' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS `administration_ph_count`,
                IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN `s`.`staff_type` = 'Administration' AND `s`.`type_of_holiday` = 'SH' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS `administration_sh_count`,
                IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN `s`.`staff_type` = 'Operation' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS `operation_staff_count`,
                `ewh`.`daily_working_hour_operation` AS `daily_working_hour_operation`,
                `ewh`.`weekly_working_hour_operation` AS `weekly_working_hour_operation`,
                IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN `s`.`staff_type` = 'Operation' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS `operation_annual_leave_count`,
                IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN `s`.`staff_type` = 'Operation' AND `s`.`type_of_holiday` = 'PH' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS `operation_ph_count`,
                IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN `s`.`staff_type` = 'Operation' AND `s`.`type_of_holiday` = 'SH' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS `operation_sh_count`,
                IFNULL(`hc`.`ph_count`, 0) AS `ph_count`,
                IFNULL(`hc`.`sh_count`, 0) AS `sh_count`,
                IFNULL(`lc`.`other_leave_count_per_staff_operation`, 0) AS `other_leave_count_per_staff_operation`,
                IFNULL(`lc`.`other_leave_count_per_staff_administration`, 0) AS `other_leave_count_per_staff_administration`,
            FROM `staff` `s`
            JOIN `property` `p` ON `s`.`property_record_key` = `p`.`record_key` AND INSTR('", par_property_record_key, "', `p`.`record_key`)
            JOIN `employment_status` `es` ON `s`.`employment_status_record_key` = `es`.`record_key`
            JOIN `efte_working_hour` `ewh` ON `s`.`property_record_key` = `ewh`.`property_record_key`
            LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT
                    `h`.`property_record_key` AS `property_record_key`,
                    IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN `h`.`type_of_holiday` = 'PH' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS `ph_count`,
                    IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN `h`.`type_of_holiday` = 'SH' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS `sh_count`
                FROM
                    `holiday` `h` 
                WHERE `h`.`year_of_holiday` = '", par_date_year, "'
                GROUP BY `h`.`property_record_key`
            ) `hc` ON `s`.`property_record_key` = `hc`.`property_record_key`
            LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT `property_record_key`, SUM((inner_s.staff_type = 'Operation') * `lt`.`default_days`) AS `other_leave_count_per_staff_operation`,
                                              SUM((inner_s.staff_type = 'Administration') * `lt`.`default_days`) AS `other_leave_count_per_staff_administration`
                FROM `leave_type` `lt`
                JOIN staff inner_s
                ON lt.property_record_key = inner_s.property_record_key
                WHERE `calculate_efte` IS TRUE
                GROUP BY `lt`.`property_record_key`
            ) `lc` ON `s`.`property_record_key` = `lc`.`property_record_key`
            WHERE `s`.`record_status` = 'Active' AND LOWER(`es`.`permanent`) = 'yes'
            GROUP BY `s`.`property_record_key`
            ) `efte`) `efte_date_type`");
END
```

Note that I do not have your schema, so this code is not necessarily correct from your schema's perspective, but it illustrates the idea and you can adjust it if needed.

Comment: In my staff `s` table, i have a column staff_type, declaring an id(user) Administration or Operation.

Comment: @tuneup90 I see. You can join leave_type with the staff table then. Editing my answer...

Comment: @tuneup90 applied an edit. In the edit I assumed that you can JOIN staff inner_s ON lt.property_record_key = inner_s.property_record_key. I have also separated the sum of operation from the sum of admin there and I think the idea is correct. But I could be wrong about your schema, as you did not share it with us. If this answer helped you solve this problem, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Lajos, but I couldn't fix my issue. As you can see in the query, it gets what type the staff is, Operation or Administration, and does the annual leave calculations, etc. But at the end for other_leave_count_per_staff, it's left joining the data from the table "leave_type" and getting only the data where calculate_efte and default days are true(1). If I set other rows that I have in leave_type table to true. It's going to make the calculations for both adminstration and operation. So there is no way to differentiate which data to pick for administration or operation.